# Changing Visual Studio 2015 Web Test response from hex to JSON

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2015, web-testing

How can the bottom pane of a Visual Studio Web Test response show JSON instead of hex values?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any way of getting just the json in the bottom panel. Some responses include the "View in html browser" link so clicking that will normally show just the json.

The workaround I normally use is to copy the entire response body from the bottom panel, paste it into a text editor (you could have a text file open in Visual Studio as a work area, but I use Notepad++ for this job) and then remove the hex part of the copied text. Both [Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355025/editor-to-select-text-that-is-inside-a-rectangle) and [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html) support column (or box or rectangular) mode allowing the entire hex part to be selected and deleted. The final action is to join the lines to for one long line. This job is so useful, but so tedious with an editor, that I wrote a little C# program to do it.

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing, sans C# program. You should post that on Github!

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it.  Create an extraction rule that selects a token.  This rule will always return positive so the token does not need to exist.  When used, it will format JSON in the response window in JSON only:

```
 namespace WebTestPlugins
{

[DisplayName("Output in JSON")]
[Description("Outputs Viewer in JSON")]
public class OutputInJSON : ExtractionRule
    {
     public override void Extract(object sender, ExtractionEventArgs e)
        {
        var response= e.Response.BodyString;
        var parseresponse = JObject.Parse(response);
        e.WebTest.Context.Add("xxxz", parseresponse.SelectToken("xxxx"));
        e.Success = true;
        return;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The above worked perfectly for me. Very helpful.